# How to order by the same attribute for multiple parent associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the models Mom, Dad and Follow which is a polymorphic association. I'm trying to put the Moms and Dads that the user is following in alphabetical order for there `name` attribute where their both mixed together. Here's what I want and my code so far.

**Example User's Followed Mom And Dad List**

```
Adam # Dad
Ashley # Mom
Brenda # Mom
Brian # Dad
```

**Models**

```
class Mom
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  # columns: name
end

class Dad
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  # columns: name
end

class Follow
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true

 belongs_to :dad, -> {where( "follows.followable_type = 'Dad'")}, foreign_key: 'followable_id'
 belongs_to :mom, -> {where( "follows.followable_type = 'Mom'")}, foreign_key: 'followable_id'

 scope :name_order, -> { includes(:dad, :mom).order("dads.name ASC",  "moms.name ASC") }
 # columns: user_id, followable_id, followable_type
end
```

**Controller**

```
def index
  @follows = current_user.follows.name_order.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Right now this orders them alphabetically but will put the Dads in front of the list and knock all the Moms to the bottom when I need them to mix. How would I do this?

Comment: you can try changing `.order("dads.name ASC",  "moms.name ASC")` to `.order("follows.name ASC")`

Comment: @bjhaid Yeah I tried `follows.name` and `follows.followable.name`.

Comment: if its just ordering the scope needs to do, then you don't need the `includes`, so you can have the scope written as `scope :name_order, -> { order("follows.name ASC") }`

Comment: @bjhaid But `Follow` doesn't have the `name` column. I tried this too with `follows.followable` as well.

Comment: can you include the generated sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
 scope :name_order, -> { 
   select("#{table_name}.*, COALESCE(dads.name, mom.name) AS follow_name").
     includes(:dad, :mom).references(:dad, :mom).order("follow_name") 
 }
```

Note: not tested.

However it seems that your model design is the biggest issue. Since it seems that each Mam and Dad is a user, why not use STI instead?

Comment: Yes, or just make a Parent class and have a field "Mom" which is boolean (so Dads have mom=false)

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I usually don't like creating such non-symmetrical boolean fields, as they are extremely hard to handle if you want to add, let's say a Grandpa. STI is extremely flexible and readable solution here. :)

Comment: If there was a requirement for Grandpa then i wouldn't have suggested it :) Personally i'm not a fan of STI, have had all sorts of hassle and pain with it in the past.  Maybe i wasn't using it right.